# Is this a fair translation of Isaiah 5:1 (LXX)?

Tags: greek, septuagint

> ᾄσω δὴ τῷ ἠγαπημένῳ ᾆσμα τοῦ ἀγαπητοῦ τῷ ἀμπελῶνί μου ἀμπελὼν ἐγενήθη τῷ ἠγαπημένῳ ἐν κέρατι ἐν τόπῳ πίονι

Now I will sing to the loved a song of the Beloved, my vineyard: "A vineyard became a loved horn in a fertile place."

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LXX text of Isa 5:1 is:

> ᾌσω δὴ τῷ ἠγαπημένῳ ᾆσμα τοῦ ἀγαπητοῦ μου τῷ ἀμπελῶνί μου. ἀμπελὼν
> ἐγενήθη τῷ ἠγαπημένῳ ἐν **κέρατι** ἐν τόπῳ πίονι.

Brenton translates this as:

> Now I will sing to my beloved a song of my beloved concerning my
> vineyard. My beloved had a vineyard on a **high hill** in a fertile place.

The OP's translation is simply more literal: κέρατι is "horn" but can also mean any prominent projection something, like a "hill" (projecting from the surrounding plain).  In Isa 5:1, "horn' does not make sense despite the fact that it accurately reflects the Hebrew קֶרֶן (qeren) = "horn".

This is why "hill" is used as the translation by almost all versions, even by very literalistic versions such as YLT, BLB, LSV, etc.

Comment: Is saying that it "became" the 'horn' or 'hill' justified in the Greek?

Comment: @Sojourner97 - the verb ἐγενήθη could either be "became" or simply "was".  The latter is that demanded by the context.